# Move all files in sub-directories to working dir and add path as prefix

Tags: bash

I want to move all files under several sub-directories to the main directory. The files are all named the same way, so want to differentiate by adding the prefix of the sub-directory they are in.

> ```
> maindir 
>    - dir1 - dir12 -filea
>                   -fileb
>           - dir13 -dir131 - filea
>                   -dir132 - filea
>    - dir2 - filea
>           - fileb
>           - filec
>    - dir3
> ```

I want them all under the main directory the script is run.

> ```
> dir1_dir12_filea
> dir1_dir12_fileb
> .
> .
> dir2_filea
> dir2_fileb
> dir2_filec
> .
> .
> ```
>
> etc

```
 for f in **/*
 do 
      dn=$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")
      bn=$(basename "$f")
      mv -- "$f" "${dn}_${bn}"
 done
```

but it only loops through 1 sub directory level deep

Comment: `($basename` should be `$(basename`

Comment: `basename $(dirname $f)` will just be `dir12` for `dir1/dir12/filename`, not `dir1_dir12`.

Comment: It seems like what you really want to do is replace all the `/` with `_` in `$f` to create the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following from in side the root directory where you want to see the copied files

```
find * -mindepth 1 -type f | sed -n 'p;s@/@_@gp' | sed 'N;s@\n@ @' | xargs -n2 mv
```

If you want to be sure it's executing the correct commands without messing up everything, first try following from the same directory.

```
find * -mindepth 1 -type f | sed -n 'p;s@/@_@gp' | sed 'N;s@\n@ @' | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

This will just echo the all the commands that will be executed. If you are happy with that, run without echo.

---

**Explanation:**

**First `sed` execution:**

```
sed -n 'p;s@/@_@gp'
```

This executes following operations on each line in the following order,

1. `p`: print current line as it is
2. `s@/@_@gp`: substitute all `/` characters of the input line with `_` characters and print it (in the next line). `g` (global) flag is for substitution to perform on all characters. Otherwise if exists after the first substitution.

Now we have two output lines for single input.

E.g.

If first `find` result is `root/dir/file1`, we need following command to be generated,

```
mv root/dir/file1 root_dir_file1
```

Following two lines come at the end of first `sed` pipe

```
root/dir/file1
root_dir_file1
```

If these two lines are merged together with a space, we get the arguments of the `mv` command. Second `sed` is just for that.

**Second `sed` execution:**

```
sed 'N;s@\n@ @'
```

This executes following operations on each line in the following order,

1. `N`: Join current input line (line in the pattern space) with the next input line with a newline character in between.
2. `s@\n@ @`: Remove the new line character with a space

Now we have the required `mv` arguments. `xargs` does the rest.

Comment: Could you explain what each sed part is doing? thank you!

Comment: @Barmar If performance is a concern, you maybe correct. But usually these are one time jobs where performance is not a concern. In that case I prefer a simple one-liner that just do the job instead of writing a script. I just shared what I would do. It's up to the OP to decide what's best for him. :)

Comment: BTW, I was wondering whether there's a way to replace two `sed` invocations with one. Is there a way to merge `pattern` and `hold` space contents without a new line in between?

Comment: In general, using `sed` to perform simple replacements in variables is a very 1990's technique, since you can now use bash's built-in `${var//old/new}`. It's not only more performant, it simplifies the code.

Comment: Can't you do the two `sed` operations with `sed -n -e 'p;s@/@_@g' -e 'N;s@\n@ @p'`

Answer (score 1):

You just want to replace all `/` with `_` in `$f`. There's no need for `dirname` or `basename`.

```
for f in **/*
do
    if ! [ -d "$f" ]
    then 
        dn=${f//\//_}
        mv -- "$f" "$dn"
    fi
done
```

Comment: if I run this, I end up with directories name dir1_dir12, dir1_13 etc on the main directory. If I run the script again, i get the dir1_dir12_filea on the main directory. Is there a way to fix it so it goes through all the subdirectories in first run?

Comment: The wildcard is matching both files and directories. Use `if` to filter out directories.